# Laravel 5.5 : Fetch many to many response on collection instance

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

I have many to many relationships between Blog and Category.

**Blog.php**

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function blog() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blog');
}
```

**create_blogs_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->length(250);
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blogs');
    }
}
```

**create_categories_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->length(250);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

**blog_category_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class BlogCategoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create ( 'blog_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer ( 'category_id' )->unsigned ();
            $table->integer ( 'blog_id' )->unsigned ();

            $table->foreign ( 'category_id' )->references ( 'id' )->on ( 'categories' );
            $table->foreign ( 'blog_id' )->references ( 'id' )->on ( 'blogs' );

            $table->primary ( [
                    'category_id',
                    'blog_id'
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists ( 'blog_category' );
    }
}
```

To get blog related to any category I can code like

```
$category = App\Category::find(1);
$category->blog->get();
```

But if I want to get blogs related to category having category id 1 & 2 in a single query. What should be the solution for this?

I tried same approach it is giving me error like 
*'Exception with message 'Property [blog] does not exist on this collection instance.'*

Comment: Some remarks to your naming: Since you define a many to many relationship, I would suggest to name the relation methods so that they reflect this: `categories()` and `blogs()`. Another thing is that Category might be the wrong term for the concept you are using, as you can put a blog in different bags, I would call this tagging. The difference to a category, is that categories are hierarchically while tags are not.

Comment: > I tried same approach it is giving me error like 'Exception with message 'Property [blog] does not exist on this collection instance.'

Please share your table definitions.

Comment: @commonsense, Thanks for your suggestions. I will follow them. Also I have updated question with the table schema.